# Given an array of integers and a number k, compute the maximum values of each subarray of length k

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

> **Problem:**
> Given an array of integers and a number k, where 1 <= k <= length of the array, compute the maximum values of each subarray of length k.
>
> Do this in O(n) time and O(k) space. You can modify the input array in-place and you do not need to store the results. You can simply print them out as you compute them.

**Example:**
Given array = [10, 5, 2, 7, 8, 7] and k = 3, we should get : [10, 7, 8, 8], since:

10 = max(10, 5, 2)

7 = max(5, 2, 7)

8 = max(2, 7, 8)

8 = max(7, 8, 7)

**Idea:**

I thought of using the std::max_element() function to solve this in which I noticed a pattern. Using the example above

std::max_element(0, 2) = 10 when 0 is the starting position and 2 is the ending position of the iterator.

std::max_element(1,3) = 7

std::max_element(2, 4) = 8

std::max_element(3,5) = 8

Thus for any k the first iterator will always be from 0 to n-2 where n is the size of the vector or array and the right iterator of max_element will always be from k-1 to n-1.

Although it is not too straight forward specifying the right iterator for various values of k. As you can see from my code I stuck on that part but I believe my idea is sound. I hope I illustrated the idea for others to understand.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

// Given an array of integers and a number k, where 1 <= k <= length of the array, compute the maximum values 
// of each subarray of length k.

// For example, given array = [10, 5, 2, 7, 8, 7] and k = 3, we should get : [10, 7, 8, 8], since :
//  10 = max(10, 5, 2)
//  7 = max(5, 2, 7)
//  8 = max(2, 7, 8)
//  8 = max(7, 8, 7)

// Do this in O(n) time and O(k) space. You can modify the input array in-place and you do not need to 
// store the results. You can simply print them out as you compute them.

void printKMax(std::vector<int>& nums, int k)
{
    int n = nums.size();
    int i = 0;
    int j = k - 1;

    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    while (j <= n - 1)
    {
        it = std::max_element(nums.begin() + i, );
        i++;
        j++;
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = { 10, 5, 2, 7, 8, 7};
    int k = 3;
    printKMax(nums, k);

    std::cin.get();
}
```

**Question:** I am having problems finding a formula for the right part of std::max_element to work for various values of k. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following link provides O(n) time and O(k) space algorithm using `std::deque`: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sliding-window-maximum-maximum-of-all-subarrays-of-size-k/ , see Method 3. Your approach seems to be O(n*k) in time because the `std::max_element` is O(k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep variables `i` and `j` as the start and the end of your inspected range, thus you need to apply `std::max_element` specifically to that range. You are looking to replace:

```
it = std::max_element(nums.begin() + i, );
```

with:

```
it = std::max_element(nums.begin() + i, nums.begin() + j + 1);
```

notice the `+ 1` part. That's because the standard convention for STL is to operate on a range that's right hand side **exclusive**.

Comment: isn't this O(k*n) ?

Comment: @zahir Yes it is, but the OP did not ask for algorithm. Neither did he ask for code review. His question was specific and targeted `std::max_element`, so I provided an answer.

Comment: I assume it is not possible to use std::max_element such that the solution would be O(n)?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx It is possible, as `max_element` returns iterator.

Comment: @bartop how does this help making the solution O(n) ?

Comment: @GeorgiGerganov It allows to get the index of the found max element

Comment: @bartop that won't help at all. You still will compare `k` elements everytime. Good algorithm would keep track of the index of the current biggest element, not use `max_element` for every set of `k` elements

Comment: Do you have any recommended data structure to use to achieve an O(n) time complexity? I hate to look at solutions but I feel like if I am pointed in the direction I could solve it on my own :)

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx, the link **Georgi** provided is quite good, but if you don't want to spoil the solution, let me give you this hint - use `std::deque` to hold indexes for the greatest elements currently inspected. You won't need it to hold more than `k` elements